# Unable to delete apostrophe using SED command on text file

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to extract numerical from a text file and have been using the SED command to remove the unwanted characters. However, I am unable to delete stray apostrophes.

This is the sample text:

```
CLASSES                                            SCORES
[u'Precipitate', u'Crystals', u'Other', u'Clear']  [0.8788071274757385, 0.050357233732938766, 0.038349077105522156, 0.03248654305934906]
```

This is the desired result:

```
0.8788071274757385, 0.050357233732938766, 0.038349077105522156, 0.03248654305934906
```

This is the code I am using:

```
echo running

sed -i '/^CLASSES/ d' ~/Desktop/testgcloud/results.txt
sed -i -e "s/Precipitate//g" -e "s/Other//g" -e "s/Crystals//g" -e "s/Clear//g" -e "s/u//g" ~/Desktop/testgcloud/results.txt
sed -i -e "s/\[//g" -e "s/\]//g" -e "s/\'//g" ~/Desktop/testgcloud/results.txt

echo finished running
```

This is the result of the code:

```
'', '', '', ''  0.8788071274757385, 0.050357233732938766, 0.038349077105522156, 0.03248654305934906
```

Also, is there a way to remove the first four commas on each line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than removing things you don't want, you may want to focus on what you do want.

`grep -Po '([0-9]+\.[0-9]+,? ?)+' input_file > ~/Desktop/testgcloud/results.txt`

This will write to results file contents matching the pattern: at least one number, decimal, at least one number and an optional comma and space. Seemingly solving your problem in only one step.

If you're really set on sed, the following will remove empty apostrophes and optional commas and spaces.

`sed "s/'',\? \?//g"`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i.bkp -e '/^CLASSES/d' -e 's/^\[[^]]*\]\s\+\[//' -e 's/\]$//' sample.txt
```

- `-e 's/^\[[^]]*\]\s\+\[//'` - delete whatever is in the first set of `[]`, the surrounding `[]` and the next `[` - [demo](https://regex101.com/r/x2c9i0/1) (note that sed uses `\+` instead of `+` but the rest is identical)
- `-e 's/\]$//'` - delete the trailing `]`